# How to get number of quarters between two dates in Java

Tags: java

I am having `fromDate` as `"01-Jan-2015"` and `toDate` as `"01-Apr-2015"`. I want to find number of quarters between `fromDate` and `toDate`. My code is like

```
String fromDate = "01-Jan-2015";
            String toDate = "01-Apr-2015";

            ArrayList<String> quarters = new ArrayList<String>();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            DateFormat dfYY = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(df.parse(fromDate));

            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal1.setTime(df.parse(toDate));

            while (cal1.getTime().after(cal.getTime())) {
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

                int quarter = month % 3 == 0 ? (month / 3) : (month / 3) + 1;

                quarters.add("Q" + quarter + "-" + dfYY.format(cal.getTime()));
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
            }
```

But it is giving output as Q1-15, Q2-15 is missing. If I enter `toDate` as"02-Apr-2015" then it is giving Q1-15, Q2-15. Please help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (cal1.getTime().after(cal.getTime()))
```

As soon as `cal1.getTime()` is "01-Apr-2015" it isnt "after" `cal.getTime()` anymore so the while loop will stop.
Thats why it doesnt make the last iteration which would give you the last Quarter.

you could go like:

```
while (cal1.getTime().after(cal.getTime()) || cal1.getTime().equals(cal.getTime()))
```

Answer (score 4):

## `IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS`

A special unit exists for this purpose in Java 8 and later: [`java.time.temporal.IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#QUARTER_YEARS) implementing [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) and its [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method.

```
long delta = 
    IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS.between(
        LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1), 
        LocalDate.of(2015, 4, 1));
System.out.println(delta); // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** See [the Answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42408143/642706) for a much simpler shorter solution.

I leave my Answer here to demonstrate the [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class that is likely to be handy in related work.

## Using java.time

Much easier with the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome old date-time classes. Those old classes are now legacy.

This Answer assumes by “quarter” you mean the standard ISO 8601 quarters, the first, second, third, and fourth groups of three months across the calendar year.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of ( 2015 , Month.JANUARY , 1 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of ( 2015 , Month.APRIL , 1 );
```

## `YearQuarter`

Add the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project library to your project to access the [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class.

Get start and stop quarters of your dates.

```
YearQuarter yqStart = YearQuarter.from ( start );
YearQuarter yqStop = YearQuarter.from ( stop );
```

Loop one quarter at a time until reaching the limit.

The code here bases the loop on the *Half-Open* approach to defining a span of time, commonly used in date-time work. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. I recommend using this approach consistently throughout your logic to avoid ambiguity, confusion, and errors. If instead you insist on the *Closed* approach (both beginning and ending are inclusive), change the `while` test to “while not after”, `while( ! yq.isAfter( yqStop ) )`.

```
int initialCapacity = ( int ) ( ( ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between ( start , stop ) / 3 ) + 3 ); // Probably `+1` is good enough, but I've not thought it through.
List<YearQuarter> yqs = new ArrayList<> ( initialCapacity );
YearQuarter yq = yqStart;
while ( yq.isBefore ( yqStop ) ) {  // Using Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
    yqs.add ( yq );  // Collect this quarter.
    // Set up next loop.
    yq = yq.plusQuarters ( 1 );  // Move to next quarter.
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start/stop: " + start + "/" + stop );
System.out.println ( "yqStart/yqStop: " + yqStart + "/" + yqStop );
System.out.println ( "yqs: " + yqs );
```

> start/stop: 2015-01-01/2015-04-01
>
> yqStart/yqStop: 2015-Q1/2015-Q2
>
> yqs: [2015-Q1]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Too awkward to use a while-loop or even download another library, see my answer.

Comment: Indeed, [your Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42408143/642706) is much better, so short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of the loop, you increment fromDate by three months. This makes it equal to toDate, so you don't get another iteration.

You need
`(cal1.getTime().after(cal.getTime())||(cal1.getTime().equals(cal.getTime())`

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods , Worked for me

```
public int getQuartersBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate) {

    int numofquarters=0;
    String[] yearquarter=null;
    Date temp=startDate;
    String[] targetYearQuarter= getYearQuarter(endDate);
    if(endDate.after(startDate)){
        yearquarter=getYearQuarter(temp);
        while(!(targetYearQuarter[0].equalsIgnoreCase(yearquarter[0])
                      && targetYearQuarter[1].equalsIgnoreCase(yearquarter[1]))){
            yearquarter=addQuarters(1,yearquarter[0],yearquarter[1]);
            numofquarters++;
        }
    }
    else{
        yearquarter=getYearQuarter(temp);
        while(!(targetYearQuarter[0].equalsIgnoreCase(yearquarter[0])
                      && targetYearQuarter[1].equalsIgnoreCase(yearquarter[1]))){
            yearquarter=addQuarters(-1,yearquarter[0],yearquarter[1]);
            numofquarters--;
        }
    }
    return  numofquarters;
}

public String[] addQuarters(int numofQuarters,String year,String quarter){

    int tempyear=Integer.parseInt(year)+(numofQuarters/4);
    int tempquarter=Integer.parseInt(quarter.replace("Q",""))+(numofQuarters%4);
    if(tempquarter>4){
        tempquarter=tempquarter-4;
        tempyear+=1;
    }
    if(tempquarter<1){
        tempquarter=tempquarter+4;
        tempyear-=1;
    }
    year=String.valueOf(tempyear);
    quarter="Q"+tempquarter;
    return new String[]{year,quarter};
}
```